# Managing Media Files from API: Storing Locally in Device Storage with Token Retrieval

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am trying to store a file locally, but I don't have the media URL. I have an API that provides an authorization token. Then, I utilize the react-native-fs library in our React Native project. This library also offers API calling features.

```
import RNFS from "react-native-fs";

export const appDirectory = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/EasyMd`;

export async function createAppDirectory() {
  try {
    const directoryExists = await RNFS.exists(appDirectory);
    if (!directoryExists) {
      await RNFS.mkdir(appDirectory);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while creating app directory: ", error);
  }
}

async function getPdfFilePrescriptionDetails() {
  try {
    setPdfLoading(true);
    await createAppDirectory();
    const path = `${appDirectory}/prescription.pdf`;
    try {
      const downloadOptions = {
        fromUrl: `${Development.BASE_URL}${Api.GET_PRESCRIPTION_API}/${id}/export`,
        toFile: `${path}`,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      };
      await Promise.all([RNFS.downloadFile(downloadOptions)]);
      setPdfUri({ url: `file://${path}` });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error saving PDF:", error);
    } finally {
      setPdfLoading(false);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Errro v", e);
  }
}
```

This is my solution. If you have another best solution, please feel free to add your comment.